# Changing from an input to a Scanner

Tags: java

I am trying to change this from an input box into a Scanner class, but i am having trouble doing so.

Its a program that takes words and makes them into a phone number here is the code that does so. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if there is something that i can do in return i would gladly do so.

```
// declare imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
public class Telephone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ask for the phone number (in letters)
        char letter;
        String inputMessage = "Please enter the number in Letters " + "or enter '#' to stop the program ";
        String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(inputMessage);
        String outputString = "";
        String outputMessage = "";
        int digit = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
        System.out.print(inputString.charAt(x)); {
            while (inputString.charAt(x) != '#') {
                letter = Character.toUpperCase(inputString.charAt(x));
                x++;
                // make sure its not a number
                if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
                    digit++;
                    switch (letter) {
                        case 'A':
                        case 'B':
                        case 'C':
                            outputString += "2";
                            break;
                        case 'D':
                        case 'E':
                        case 'F':
                            outputString += "3";
                            break;
                        case 'G':
                        case 'H':
                        case 'I':
                            outputString += "4";
                            break;
                        case 'J':
                        case 'K':
                        case 'L':
                            outputString += "5";
                            break;
                        case 'M':
                        case 'N':
                        case 'O':
                            outputString += "6";
                            break;
                        case 'P':
                        case 'Q':
                        case 'R':
                        case 'S':
                            outputString += "7";
                            break;
                        case 'T':
                        case 'U':
                        case 'V':
                            outputString += "8";
                            break;
                        case 'W':
                        case 'X':
                        case 'Y':
                        case 'Z':
                            outputString += "9";
                    }
                    if (digit == 7) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (digit == 3) {
                        outputString += "-";
                    }
                }
                inputMessage = "Enter another set of telephone letters";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputString, "Telephone Program", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to indent your code? It really helps readability...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions. Primarily, SO is not a forum where you ask unfocused questions like "help me improve my code" or, "tell me what's wrong" without giving any details other than the code itself.  Please tell us what you're having trouble with, and show what you've done so far to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Btw: Maybe you think about using the ascii value of the characters to avoid the massive switch cases. 'A' is 65, 'B' 66 and so on. All but the last block are 3.. (v-65)/3)+2 or somethinkg alike should return the right numbers for all but the last block.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the line where you show the JOptionPane as follows,

```
//String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(inputMessage);
System.out.println(inputMessage);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputString = sc.nextLine();
```

so you could do the following,

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Telephone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ask for the phone number (in letters)
        char letter;
        String inputMessage = "Please enter the number in Letters " + "or enter '#' to stop the program ";
//        String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(inputMessage);

        System.out.println(inputMessage);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = sc.nextLine();

        String outputString = "";
        String outputMessage = "";
        int digit = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(inputString.charAt(x));
        }

        while (inputString != null && inputString.trim().length() > 0 && inputString.charAt(x) != '#') {
            letter = Character.toUpperCase(inputString.charAt(x));
            x++;
            // make sure its not a number
//                if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
            if (x >= inputString.length()) {
                x = 0;
                System.out.println("\n" + outputString);
//                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputString, "Telephone Program", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
//                inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(inputMessage);
                System.out.println(inputMessage);
                inputString = sc.nextLine();
            } else if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
                digit++;
                switch (letter) {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C':
                        outputString += "2";
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F':
                        outputString += "3";
                        break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'I':
                        outputString += "4";
                        break;
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L':
                        outputString += "5";
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O':
                        outputString += "6";
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S':
                        outputString += "7";
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V':
                        outputString += "8";
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z':
                        outputString += "9";
                }
                if (digit == 7) {
                    break;
                }
                if (digit == 3) {
                    outputString += "-";
                }
            }
//                }
            inputMessage = "Enter another set of telephone letters";
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + outputString);
//        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputString, "Telephone Program", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

Comment: When i replaced it with the modification and ran the program i got CCCCCCCCC as the output

Comment: Sorry, i thought it worked as you wanted. I edited the answer with a full working example showing what i think you want.